# How much antimatter enters an ordinary human body on a day-to-day basis?

Tags: antimatter

Over the course of an ordinary person's day, antimatter (here used to mean negative baryons), generated by various physical mechanisms, enters their body.  If all the antimatter that entered the body of an ordinary person over the course of a single day was collected, what would its mass be?  A Fermi estimation is a good enough answer, although more accuracy is welcome.

Comment: I assume you mean net negative baryon number: It would be absurd to start counting negative lepton number such as positron input, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos you are correct in your assumption.  Ignore positrons, as their mass should be negligible.  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: You are aware the antimatter won't survive long in you, but will annihilate with your nuclei, right?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, I am aware of that fact.  I just want to know how much enters your body (this is a magic system I'm devising, so, in-story, it won't annihilate, because magic)

Comment: Go figure :) [Flux of light antimatter nuclei near earth,
induced by Cosmic Rays in the Galaxy and in the atmosphere.](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0503544)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an experimental](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/303463/fulltext/34617.text.html) number in a window of energies:

> and we obtain an antiproton/proton ratio upper limit from our data in the energy range of overlap with Buffington et al. (1981) (200–300 MeV) as 1.3 × 10^-5 (95% confidence level).

[Here is another](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/303463/fulltext/34617.text.html) number:

> Thus a thin, horizontal plane detector will record a *flux per m2 per second* of about 150 muons and, if its wall has 1 MeV electron stopping power, 70 electrons, and 1 proton.

A ratio of 10^-5  to the proton means that to get one antiproton per second  you will need 100.000 square meters

For the purposes you are thinking about this is zero antiprotons, as the human body is much smaller than that.

Comment: So given the usually taken human body surface of 1.7 m^2, this gives about one antiproton per minute.

Comment: And using 1.6726219e-27 kilograms per antiproton, that gives us roughly 2.4e-21 grams of antiprotons per day.  That's rather disappointing.  We won't even get a joule per lifetime collecting antimatter at that rate.

Comment: you get 120 protons per minute per 2 metersquared, but 0.0012 antiprotons per minute, the ration is 10^-5

Comment: Ah, I misread your final analysis.  In either case, however, it seems that the amount of antimatter is far too small to be of any practical use at all.

Comment: So one antiproton per day?

Comment: @Ben  order of magnitude for an area of 2meters squared.

Comment: @Ben - An antiproton a day keeps the physicist away!